# Finding linear combination of rows to get final row in rank deficient matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Given a $4\times 4$ rank $3$ matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&a_{34}\\
a_{41}&a_{42}&a_{43}&a_{44}
\end{bmatrix}
there are rationals $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb Q$ such that $$\alpha\cdot\mbox{row}_1+\beta\cdot\mbox{row}_2+\gamma\cdot\mbox{row}_3+\delta\cdot\mbox{row}_4=0$$ holds.

How to find these rationals $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Gaussian elimination?

Comment: You can’t guarantee that these coefficients are rational unless the matrix entries are also rational. Are they?

Comment: @amd That is correct ok and then if I replace $0$ by $\epsilon$ then is it possible?